# Doctrine Relationship on a namespaced table

Tags: database, namespaces, doctrine, relationships

I have several doctrine models that have relationships to other models. Let's call those `ItemsOne`, `ItemsTwo`, `ItemsThree`. Each has a relationship defined to the `Products` doctrine class (products table) and the relationship is defined as:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'Models_Products as Products',
    array(
     'local'   => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'product_id',
    )
);
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there.

I also have another table (`prices`) which stores namespaced data. By that I mean that the particular table stores data based on a predefined key (i.e. `Vinyl`, `CD`, `DVD`) so the rows would show something like this:

```
media_namespace  entity_id  quantity    unit_price
CD               4          1000        0.99
DVD              4          2500        1.25
CD               7          3750        0.25
Vinyl            15         75          4.25
```

The `entity_id` is the id of each of the models accessing this table. So for instance `CD/entity_id = 4` refers to `ItemsOne` model, `DVD/entity_id = 4` refers to the `ItemsTwo` model, etc.

I want to create a relationship - and I don't know if this can be done - whereas it will be namespaced in the model. So in the above snipped for the products relationship I need something like (for the ItemsOne model):

```
$this->hasMany(
    'Models_Prices as Prices',
    array(
     'local'   => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'entity_id',
    )
);
```

However the above will return all the prices with the `entity_id` matching the `ItemsOne` table which is partly correct. In the above example if `entity_id = 4`, it will return the `CD` record but also the `DVD` one which is not what I need.  I want it to be filtering the data based on the `media_namespace` table. So in short what I need is:

```
prices.media_namespace = 'CD' AND prices.entity_id = itemsone.id
```

Can the above be reflected in a `hasMany` relationship in Doctrine? I have searched and cannot something that would help.

Any pointers are more than appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Doctrine subclasses. Create a subclass for each namespace. This will let you reference a specific set of data by class name.

- class Models_Price

  - subclass Models_Price_CD
  - subclass Models_Price_DVD
  - subclass Models_Price_Vinyl

In the Price class, you'll need to specify the following:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->setSubclasses(
        array(
            'Price_CD' => array(
                'media_namespace' => 'CD',
            ),
            'Price_DVD' => array(
                'media_namespace' => 'DVD',
            ),
            'Price_Vinyl' => array(
                'media_namespace' => 'Vinyl',
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Let's make the assumption that ItemsOne uses namespace CD, ItemsTwo uses namespace DVD, and ItemsThree uses namespace Vinyl.

For this situation, you would add the following relationship to each class:

ItemsOne:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'Models_Price_CD as Prices',
    array(
     'local'   => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'entity_id',
    )
);
```

ItemsTwo:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'Models_Price_DVD as Prices',
    array(
     'local'   => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'entity_id',
    )
);
```

ItemsThree:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'Models_Price_Vinyl as Prices',
    array(
     'local'   => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'entity_id',
    )
);
```

Now, each of the Prices relations will return only what you expect. Doctrine, seeing the subclass, will automatically namespace all the queries you perform on that table.